# Get value of json string

Tags: json

```
[
    {
        "type": "spline",
        "name": "W dor\u0119czeniu",
        "color": "rgba(128,179,236,1)",
        "mystring": 599,
        "data": ...
    }
]
```

I am trying to access this json as `json['W doręczeniu']['mysting']`, and I get no value why is that?

Comment: JSON is just a method of storing data, what language are you using to attempt to access this data?

Comment: Sure it's not just a typo? "mystring" and not "mysting"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of "W doręczeniu" is not a key, so you cannot use it to get a value. Since your json string is an array you'll have to do `json[0].name`to access the first (and only) element in the array, which happens to be the object. Of course, this is assuming `json` is the variable you store the array into.

```
var json = [{"type":"spline","name":"W dor\u0119czeniu","color":"rgba(128,179,236,1)","mystring":599}];

console.log(json[0].mystring); //should give you what you want.
```

EDIT:
To get the last element in a js array, you can simply do this:

```
console.log( json[json.length -1].mystring ); // same output as the previous example
```

'length - 1' because js arrays are indexed at 0. There's probably a million and one ways to dynamically get the array element you want, which are out of the scope of this question.

Comment: And how can I get json[0] replacing 0 with the last element? its dynamically created so how can i get it?

Comment: I know this question and answer is really old, but could you mark it as correct if it is the one that works for you?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access the index "W doręczeniu" but that's not an index it's a value. Also, what you seem to have is an array of JSON objects.
The [ at the start marks the array, the first element of which is your JSON object. The JSON obj begins with the {
You're also trying to use a [ ], but JSON values are accessed with the dot operator.
I'm not sure which index you're actually trying to access, but try something like this:

```
var x = json[0].mystring;
```

Comment: JavaScript objects can be accessed in a few ways. You can't use dot notation if the key has a non-word character in it. Although doing that is not standard practice, it is allowed, so  if his key was indeed "W doręczeniu", he could not do `json[0].W doręczeniu` because it would be looking for the "W" key. And you can't do `json[0]."W doręczeniu"`, so your only recourse is to use the array brackets `[]`.